# Editing crontab from within rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been using whenever to easily configure soem cron jobs I need to run for my rails application. At this point however, I would like the user of the web application to be able to control the frequency that this job gets run, as well as whether or not it gets run at all. Basically, I want them to be able to select how often, in minutes to run and have a enable/disable for it as well. I don't believe you can do this with whenever, but I may be mistaken. Is there any other gem to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps check out http://cronedit.rubyforge.org/